# Is it required to place "struct" in front of a struct instance in c++ when you use c header files?

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am learning how to do socket programming, and I tried to recreate the functionality of a c program:
https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/showip.c

In `c++` (because I prefer c++ and its the language I intend to implement with) and it uses the headers:

```
stdio.h 
string.h
sys/types.h
sys/socket.h
netdb.h
arpa/inet.h
netinet/in.h
```

I replaced `stdio.h` with `iostream` and `string.h` with `cstring` in my code.

I essentially typed line by line the code in his program, reading docs as I went to try and understand each function and struct. I know that in c++ it is not required (as in c) to precede instances of a struct with the **`struct`** keyword, so anywhere there was a reference to a struct in his code I just omitted it.

In compilation, all of the structs in netinet/in.h were undefined! After some time of troubleshooting and various errors, I just downloaded his program source and made sure it wasn't an issue with my standard library (Cygwin is iffy?) Worked like a charm, but I still wanted c++.

I changed all `stdio` stuff to `iostream` and compiled it with `g++` instead of `gcc` and it still worked! The only thing that was different was having **`struct`** in front of addrinfo and the other structs.

*Is it required to place **`struct`** in front of a struct instance in c++ when you use c header files?*

Comment: This question can be investigated with a two-line program: `#include <netinet/in.h>` followed by a definition that either includes `struct` or doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use all the `C` stuff (headers) in your program, at the end of the day it is recognized as a `C++` source by your system if the file ends with `.cpp` extension. So, if you don't need to put **struct** in front of every `struct` instance as long as your source file is a `C++` source file, it shouldn't show any compilation error.

That implies NO as the answer to your question.

Edit: As @JesperJuhl pointed out, this is not always true. Exceptions happen on AiX, VMS, Novell NetWare, DOS system. In that case, you'll need to use `struct` keyword before every instance.

Comment: "it is recognized as a C++ source by your system if the file ends with .cpp extension" - That is *very* system and compiler dependant and *definitely not* universally true. Try AiX, VMS, Novell NetWare, DOS and their respective system compilers on for size. Just as an example

Answer (score 2):

"Is it required to place "struct" in front of a struct instance in c++" - In *general*; No, That's a C'ism. Exceptions do exist though.

Comment: Stated broadly, this is incorrect. Sometimes, you are required to do that.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok. Yes, I know. But this was not a language-lawyer question so I didn't want to dig into the details of when there may be a function with the same name as a struct (like `stat`) and other situations where the keyword is needed. In *general* it is not needed in C++. The devil is in the details and yes, I agree there *are* details.